# Downsize image in php for fast viewing and still keep quality

Tags: php, image, gd, imagick

We will be uploading images that are about 3 megabytes in size in excess of 2,500px.  I have my code working for uploading multiple images and would now like to have them resized or down sized to about 500px wide web viewing size.  I would like it to keep a good quality but not take long to download.  I'll have a preview and when you click on it open in lightbox for a bigger image which will be 500px or whatever I can get away with and still have it download fast.

I would be grateful if someone could help me modify my code to resize to 500px wide proportionally.

```
  $valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp");
$max_file_size = 100 * 1024 * 1024; //100 mb
$path = "PW-Files/$listingid/images/"; // Upload directory
$count = 0;

if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
    // Loop $_FILES to execute all files
    foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $f => $name) {     
    if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 4) {
        continue; // Skip file if any error found
    }          
    if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 0) {              
        if ($_FILES['files']['size'][$f] > $max_file_size) {
            $message[] = "$name is too large!.";
            continue; // Skip large files
        }
        elseif( ! in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $valid_formats) ){
            $message[] = "$name is not a valid format";
            continue; // Skip invalid file formats
        }
        else{ // No error found! Move uploaded files 
        $ext = end(explode('.', $name));
        $newname = rand(10,10000) . rand(10,1000) . "." . "$ext";
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path.$newname))   {
                $count++; // Number of successfully uploaded files
            }
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use imagecopyresampled to resize the image.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a please give me the codes question, and shows no attempt to solve the problem by the OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To resize your image, you can use [WideImage](http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/) ( php library for image manipulation ).

It provides easy way to resize your image like:

```
$image = WideImage::load( 'yourImage.jpg' );
$resizedImage = $image->resize( $width, $height );
```

You can also save the file  after resizing.

```
$resizedImage->saveToFile( 'filename.jpg' );
```

For more info, see their [documentation](http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/documentation/manipulating-images/).